# how to send sensor data to the user using email

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, notifications, sensors

I'm currently working with raspberry pi and using DHT11 to read temperature and humidity values every second. I have to send the notification to the user through email. Here's my code that showing sensor data every second, I don't know how to send email to the user. I only need to send a notification when the humidity below 40.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime
import os


# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=dht11_pin)

    while True:

        cnt += 1
        if cnt%limit_sec == 0 or cnt == 1:

            result = instance.read()
            if result.is_valid():

                if previous_temperature != result.temperature or previous_humidity != result.humidity:

                    previous_temperature = result.temperature
                    previous_humidity = result.humidity

                    counter += 1
                    rightnow = datetime.datetime.now()

                    if result.humidity>=40:
                        print(str(counter)+". Last valid input: " )
                        print("Date: " + rightnow.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
                        print("Time: " + rightnow.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
                        print("Status: Your plant is on the good condition.")
                        print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
                        print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)

                    else:
                        print(str(counter)+". Last valid input: " )
                        print("Date: " + rightnow.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
                        print("Time: " + rightnow.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
                        print("Status: Your plant is on the bad condition. Please open the water supply.")
                        print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
                        print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)

            else:
                print "Invalid result!"
                pass

        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send an email like this:

```
import smtplib

sender = 'my@address.de'
receiver = 'your@address.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'Humidity below 40'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver

# e.g. gmail account
s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
s.starttls()
s.login('username', 'password')
s.sendmail(sender, [receiver], msg.as_string())
s.close()
```

Comment: You are welcome, and if it answered your question, give it a green checkmark

Comment: Actually, I want to send the result for humidity less than 40. I want to send date, time, temperature and humidity result at that time the sensor detects humidity of less than 40.

Comment: Then only a simple step is missing: put the code to send the email into the `else` statement and include `result.humidity` in `msg['Subject']`

Comment: sorry, i don't understand

Comment: If I knew where your disunderstanding lies ... ;) God bless you!

Comment: I don't understand this:  put the code to send the email into the else statement and include result.humidity in msg['Subject']

Comment: Okay. Thanks for helping me.